Workaround for a vector of types in rust?

pub trait Props {
   // ...
}

// One, Two and Three implement Props
pub type One = LengthyServiceDefWithGenerics<...>;
pub type Two = AnotherServiceDefWithGenerics<...>;
pub type Three = YetAnother<...>;


impl Builder {
   pub fn build_it<P: Props>(&self) -> Elem<P> {
     Elem::new(self);
   }
}

// somewhere else in the codebase
// there might be more instances to be built than just a, b, c
let builder = Builder.new();
let a = builder.build_it::<One>();
let b = builder.build_it::<Two>();
let c = builder.build_it::<Three>();

This is existing code, quite simplified, in a large code base, and it runs.
As a rust rookie, I first naively thought I could just abstract this away by doing something like
impl Outer {
  pub fn new(props: Vec<Props>) {
     let builder = Builder::new();
     for p in props.iter() {
        builder.build_it::<p>();
     }
  }
}

but I guess that has several issues:

As far as I know there is no way to make a vector of just types in rust. Types don't take space in memory.
Even if they did, the iteration would pick an instance of that vector which probably can't just be passed to the function like this build_it::<p>

Is there a way to achieve this? I guess it needs to be done in a very different way.
I invested quite some time in simplifying quite a large codebase involved for this question, but there might things missing in this simplification, or the simplification stopped to make sense. I sincerely apoologise if this is the case. I also searched quite some time around to see if there are already existing questions, but "vector of types" yields results with quite different contexts.
I still hope it became clear what I want to do.

Rust doesn't have anything like Zig's comptime, but a macro can work in this case, even if it'll be less flexible.

Alternatively, you can turn static dispatch into dynamic dispatch.

Usually sets of types are expressed through tuple types (T1, T2, T3, ...) or cons lists (Cons<T1, Cons<T2, Cons<T3, Nil>>>) often with macros or other helpers for using those type constructions. There are crates (like hlist2) that may work for you.

I'm not specifically a Rust expert, but .. If you know all the indices statically (meaning they are all compile-time constants), you don't really need a vector. You always can write a_3 instead of a[3].  And each a_i can be a type. OTOH if the index is not statically known, all a[i] must statically look the same, so any difference between them is dynamic and this begs for dynamic dispatch. Here each a[i] must be (a reference to) an object if the same static type, but the dynamic type may differ.

In what way do you use a, b and c?

Each represents a service, which then works with async channels to get/send stuff.

Can't you simply use an enum?

IIUC, a macro like the following is equivalent to your Outer::new:
macro_rules! build_all {
   ($($t:ty),*) => {
      let builder = Builder::new();
      $(builder.build_it::<$t>();)*
   }
}

fn main() {
    build_all!(i32, f32, String);
}

Playground
Note however that this can only be a compile-time construct. There is no way in Rust to build and use a list of types dynamically at run-time.

OK great, I am very new to makros so I will need to digest this. But first - conceptually, isn't makro just some kind of code generator? Why would a code generator be able to achieve something that "regular" code won't?

The macro is a code generator. You can see the generated code on the playground with Tools → Expand macros. The difference is the loop: the macro expansion unrolls the loop and so is equivalent to writing the three calls to build_it one after the other.

Macro
struct Builder;
struct Elem<P: Props> {
    props: P,
}

trait Props {}
impl Props for i32 {}
impl Props for i64 {}
impl Props for f32 {}
impl Props for f64 {}

impl Builder {
    fn new() -> Self {
        todo!()
    }
    fn build<P: Props>(&self) -> Elem<P> {
        todo!()
    }
}

macro_rules! build_all {
    ($builder:expr,$($t: ty), +) =>{
        ($($builder.build::<$t>()), + )
    }
}

fn main() {
    let builder = Builder::new();

    let build_all: Elem<i32> = build_all!(builder, i32);

    let build_all: (Elem<i32>, Elem<i64>) = build_all!(builder, i32, i64);

    let build_all: (Elem<i32>, Elem<i64>, Elem<f32>) = build_all!(builder, i32, i64, f32);

    let build_all: (Elem<i32>, Elem<i64>, Elem<f32>, Elem<f64>) = build_all!(builder, i32, i64, f32, f64);
}


I suggest doing it with macro. If you don't want to change Elem<T>, here's an example:
trait Props {}

struct A {}
impl Props for A {}
struct B {}
impl Props for B {}
struct C {}
impl Props for C {}

struct Elem<T: Props> {
    // placeholder marker to make it compile
    maker: PhantomData<T>,
}
struct Builder {
    // stuff
}

impl Builder {
    fn build_it<T: Props>(&self) -> Elem<T> {
        Elem::new()
    }
}

impl<T: Props> Elem<T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Elem { maker: PhantomData }
    }
}

macro_rules! elems {
    ($builder: expr; $($t:ty),*) => {
        (
            $($builder.build_it::<$t>(),)*
        )
    };
}

fn foo() -> (Elem<A>, Elem<B>, Elem<C>) {
    elems!(Builder {}; A, B, C)
}

The result of the macro is a tuple, so you can't do Vec things with it.
The reason is because Elem<A> and Elem<B> and Elem<C> are not the same type, so rust can't put them in the same Vec<T>.
If you really want to create a Vec<Elem>, you need to change Elem<T> to use dynamic dispatch like so
trait Props {}

#[derive(Default)]
struct A {}
impl Props for A {}
#[derive(Default)]
struct B {}
impl Props for B {}
#[derive(Default)]
struct C {}
impl Props for C {}

struct Elem {
    // put stuff on Heap to make Elem fix sized at compile time
    inner: Box<dyn Props>,
}
struct Builder {
    // stuff
}

impl Builder {
    fn build_it<T: Props + Default + 'static>(&self) -> Elem {
        Elem::new(Box::new(T::default()))
    }
}

impl Elem {
    fn new(item: Box<dyn Props>) -> Self {
        Elem { inner: item }
    }
}

macro_rules! elems {
    ($builder: expr; $($t:ty),*) => {
        vec![
            $($builder.build_it::<$t>(),)*
        ]
    };
}

fn foo() -> Vec<Elem> {
    elems!(Builder {}; A, B, C)
}

If you want to know more about writing and understanding macros, I suggest reading the Macros chapter of the Rust Book.
